# Clipboard RichTextBox copy/paste text & images only

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

Using either shortcut keys or mouse right-click, how to copy only selected text and images from a RichTextBox to the Clipboard, and also paste them into a RichTextBox?

I can get the text using:
Clipboard.SetText(rtf.SelectedText)

or the images, not both together.

Comment: Do Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V not work?

Comment: Yes, however I need to limit the selections to text and images.